# PrimeNG overlaypanel error "this.engine.setProperty is not a function"

Tags: angular, primeng

I included OverlayPanelModule as @NgModule import in parent.module.ts. In child.component.html I pasted

```
<p-overlayPanel [dismissable]="false" #overlay> Content </p-overlayPanel>
```

and get the following error:

```
ERROR TypeError: this.engine.setProperty is not a function at AnimationRenderer.setProperty (animations.es5.js?28df:502) at DebugRenderer2.setProperty (core.es5.js?de3d:13729) at setElementProperty (core.es5.js?de3d:9383) at checkAndUpdateElementValue (core.es5.js?de3d:9302) at checkAndUpdateElementInline (core.es5.js?de3d:9238) at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (core.es5.js?de3d:12323) at checkAndUpdateNode (core.es5.js?de3d:12269) at debugCheckAndUpdateNode (core.es5.js?de3d:13130) at debugCheckRenderNodeFn (core.es5.js?de3d:13109) at Object.eval [as updateRenderer] (OverlayPanel.html:2)
```

I also checked the sample source code on github but no clue what is missing here.

version used is "primeng": "^4.1.3"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was not related to overlay panel only. I used angular animations version 4.2.6, downgrading to 4.2.0 solved the issue.